# How to export (hg archive) a named branch in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, build, branch, jenkins

I am setting up continuous integration (Jenkins) with Mercurial and am trying to configure it to build multiple releases (branches). I have it working for the default branch using `hg archive` to export (svn term) the code to perform a clean build. Now I'd like to do the same for a named branch.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to specify the named branch for hg archive. There is an option to specify a tag (or revision) with the -r option, but I don't see anything about branches.

As perhaps a related issue, it seems that when I do an `hg archive`, it exports from the working directory rather than the repository. This means when someone commits code, we have to do `hg update` first before `hg archive` to get the code into the build. Perhaps I can configure Jenkins to do this automatically?

As is probably apparent, I am coming from an svn background and am not sure that I have my head completely wrapped around Mercurial, so let me know the better way if I am approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `--rev` argument will accept a named branch.  For example, you may do something like:

```
hg archive --rev <branch_name> <DESTINATION>
```

This gives you an archive of the repo at the tip of the named branch.

See [`hg help revisions`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revisions) for details.

Comment: Ah... that wasn't clear from the archive documentation. Thanks.